# gvim AnsiEsc plugin

Tags: linux, vim, plugins

When I try to source AnsiEsc.vba from gvim I get:

> Error detected while processing function vimball#Vimball

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Without telling us more about the particular error message, it's hard to diagnose the problem, but you may have an old or corrupted installation of the Vimball plugin. Try downloading and installing a recent version from either

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502 (latest stable)
- http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIMBALL (latest alpha/beta)

Edit: The old AnsiEsc plugin version v2 that works without the *conceal* functionality is [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=3653).

Comment: @Meir If the problem is really corrupted installation just reinstall vim as it is part of standard distribution. If it got corrupted who knows what else may have got corrupted as well. Though you’d better post the full error message, problem is likely in something else.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat. I'm new at this, didn't understand that I had downloaded an archived file. O.K. so now I have everything extracted and installed under ~/.vim directory (/plugin, /autoload) but it's still not working. I'm running /usr/bin/gvim -o. ver 7.0.237. Thanks

Comment: @Ingo Karkat **O.K. THANKS** when I type :AsciEsc it actually works. But I still get: `E402 Garbage after pattern: conceal^I'<some reg exp>'`. I guess I'm still missing something ?

Comment: Your Vim version 7.0 is outdated. The _conceal_ keyword Vim is complaining about was introduced with Vim 7.3. Upgrade Vim (recommended) or find an older plugin version that still supports Vim 7.0 (not recommended).

Comment: @Ingo Karkat I'm running on a company server, so I'll have to install gvim 7.3 in my home directory or find & install the plugin.(I'm not allowed to do either:) **THANKS**